# Display long text with applescript, preferably with a scrollbar

Tags: applescript, macos

How can applescript display a long text that does not fit on the screen? I am looking for command similar to "display dialog", yet where I would be able to read the whole text. "display dialog" amended with a scrollbar would do the job.

Thanks

Comment: Sans using something like, e.g. `display dialog "" default answer veryLongSentence`, I do not believe that basic AppleScript has a command to do what you are asking. Why not display the text in a TextEdit window. Also note using `display dialog` on the aforementioned example that the width of the dialog box is quit narrow in relation to the size of the screen and the text would be highlighted. Whereas with setting it in a TextEdit window, one could set the size and placement of the window along with the text to be displayed.

Comment: Cool, for what i need the "default answer" trick is fine. thanks a lot

Comment: Did you know that the bottom edge of a notification box can be dragged vertically down to increase the box size whilst they appear on screen from the notification centre ?  Any overflow then comes into view.  Of course, this requires you to use the mouse to perform the action, so might not fit your purpose.  But try it with `display notification "Long sentence"`.